# Wicket 9: stale page exception no longer handled by recreating the page

Tags: exception, tabs, wicket, default, stalestateexception

After upgrading from Wicket 1.5 to Wicket 9, our users now may sometimes cause a Stale Page Exception by:

- Duplicating a tab
- Clicking a link, submitting a form, etc., in the second tab
- Returning to the first tab
- Trying to click a link, submit a form, etc., in the first tab

In the past, i.e. 1.5, Wicket's default behaviour on encountering a stale page exception was to recreate the original page. This gave the users a smooth and trouble-free experience, requiring just one extra click on the link or button in order to achieve their aim. They grew used to duplicating tabs, and wish to continue doing so.

Now, in Wicket 9, a stale page exception triggers a 500 error, which is seriously undesirable behaviour.

How can we return to the default behaviour that we had before? There must be a relevant setting somewhere, but I don't know where.

I would be most grateful if anyone can tell me how to change this setting. Thanks!

Comment: This is not what is happening here: a StalePageException is thrown and DefaultExceptionMapper#mapExpectedExceptions() maps this to a RenderPageRequestHandler. Can you try with wicket-examples or create a quickstart?

Comment: Thank you, Sven, am creating a quickstart now.

Comment: Thank you again, Sven, after doing a quickstart for both 9.0.0 and 9.9.0, I see the error occurs in 9.0.0 but not in 9.9.0. Also, after searching the Wicket mailing list, I now see there is a note that stale page exception is fixed in 9.3.0. After upgrading my actual real application, as opposed to the quickstart, and checking that the problem is fixed, I will mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by upgrading to Wicket 9.3.0 or later.